# How can a sails client(browser) can listen to socket messages emitted(blasted) from different ports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, sails.js

How can a sails client (browser) listen to socket messages emitted from different ports ?

The sails client is running on port **8085**. I am trying to listen to sockets which are emitted from different ports (one port is the same **8085** and the other port is **8081**).

Does anyone have any clue how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of your set-up, do you have two sails processes running on the same server using different ports?

Regardless, I would recommend using redis for socket implementations, if you're not already. Here's some (not exactly helpful) [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-sockets). I'm not exactly sure this will solve your situation (I think it might), but either way this is the preferred method for horizontally scaling sails.js applications that support websockets.

Comment: I have already tried redis . But there is an issue. The session is cleared out every time I used multiple sockets.

Comment: There are two sails processes running on the same server using different ports

Comment: Have you tried using redis to store sessions as well? Here's a more complete [doc](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment/scaling) on scaling sails. Although you're on the same server, the same concepts should pertain to your situation.

Comment: I have changed the sockets.js and session.js of the sails app running on port 8085.Now the socket.js looks like this : adapter: 'socket.io-redis',
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 6379,            and    session.js  looks like this -  adapter: 'connect-redis' . But still the session is cleared out in 8085 when it tries to listen for a socket message from 8081 . where am I making the mistake ?

Comment: session is cleared when I use - var socket1 = io.sails.connect('http://localhost:8081'); There are no errors in the browser console